# Number of occurrences needed to make an event probable (>95%)

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I'm trying to get a formula for the number of tries $x$ I need to make $P(A)$ occur with 95% probability $P(C)$.

$$P(C) = \sum_{i=0}^x i \bigcup A $$
$$P(C) = \sum_{i=0}^x (P(i) + P(A) - P(i)*P(A))$$

I can decompose this summation as follows:

$$P(C) = \sum_{i=0}^x (P(i) + P(A)) - \sum_{i=0}^x (P(i) * P(A))$$

These are equivalent to:

$$P(C) = P(A)x - P(A)^x$$

Okay, I got it one step further:

$$\frac{P(C)}{P(A)} = x - P(A)^{x-1} $$

Edit 2: I think I'm onto something.

$$Log(\frac{P(C)}{P(A)} - x ) = Log(P(A)^{x-1})$$
$$Log(\frac{P(C)}{P(A)} - x ) = (x-1)Log(P(A))$$

Here is the part where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to isolate the $x$. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax

Comment: @ZevChonoles thanks, I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an event $A$ with probability $P(A)$ and want to find the number of independent trials to have at least $C=0.95$ chance of one or more successes, it is easier to find the probability of all failures and subtract from $1$.  The chance of no successes in $n$ trials is $(1-P(A))^n$, so the chance of at least one is $1-(1-P(A))^n$  So we have $$C=1-(1-P(A))^n\\(1-P(A))^n=1-C\\n=\frac {\log(1-C)}{\log(1-P(A))}$$

Your derivation doesn't work because $P(i)$ is not used correctly.  It appears to be the chance that you get at least one success in $i$ tries.  You can then write a recurrence $P(i)=P(i-1)+P(A)-P(i-1)P(A)$ but you don't want to be summing over $i$.

Comment: Thanks, fantastic answer. I didn't think of flipping things around! Edit = The correct version of my approach is even more scary.

Comment: @elite5472:  This is often done in probability calculations.  Calculating one can be much easier than the other.